# Как сверстать такие укосы?

Tags: html, css

Как сверстать то что на картинке?

[image: Пример]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Мы все учились по немногу когда-нибудь и как-нибудь

В общем по шагам :

1) создаём обёртку которая будет скрывать не нужные части.

2) создаём блок со свойством `transform:skew(-25deg)`.

3) *rgba* позволяет сделать фон который имеет прозрачность в отчие от *hex*.

и на выходе получаем это :

```css
.blocks {
  width: 140px;
  height: 40px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.block {
  width: 150px;
  height: 40px;
  background: rgba(48, 87, 123, .9);
  transform: skew(25deg)translate(-20px, 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="blocks">
  <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Хороший ответ, как я про skew забыл.. Мой пример уж точно на костылях "хороших"))

Comment: бывает -- на skew вообще много вкусного делается

Comment: Так и знал, что что-то упущу))

Answer (score 1):

Если не нужно поддерживать IE лучше сделать через `clip-path`:

```css
.test{
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, calc(100% - 50px) 0, 100% 100%, 0 100px);
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
```